# Can I install a GUI for firewalld?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, gui, firewalld

I have installed `firewalld` as it is more advanced than gufw, however I see that `firewalld` does not come with a GUI and I'm not going to be the only one using it so I am wondering if there is some sort of GUI that I can install for it? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18.

Comment: How did you install `firewalld`?  There is supposed to also be a GUI named `firewalld-config`, but the article I read about this was for Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: The graphical interface is lagging. See https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD#Graphical_Configuration_Tool . Last time I looked it was not working.

Comment: See also https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html

Comment: @CharlesGreen: I ran the command `sudo apt-get install firewalld`.

Comment: It is possible firewalld will conflict with ufw, so I would remove ufw / gufw

Comment: The [old article](http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/10/24/replace-ufw-with-firewalld-on-ubuntu-14-10/) suggested installing `sudo apt-get install firewall-applet`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The graphical tool is `firewall-config`

[image: firewalld]

Ubuntu man page - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/firewall-config.1.html

Although the man page states firewall-config is packaged as part of firewalld,

> **Provided by: firewalld_0.3.4-1_all**

it is packaged separate in `firewall-applet`

Thank you Paranoid Panda for pointing that out.

```
sudo apt-get install firewall-applet
```

IMO it does not offer all the command line options available to firewallD but it may work for you.

For additional information on firewalld see

https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD

and

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html

Note: It is possible, highly likely in face, ufw will conflict with firewalld, as such I would advise you purge ufw/gufw

Comment: It can't find that package...

Comment: It is part of firewalld - From the man page "Provided by: firewalld_0.3.4-1_all"

Comment: Well, when I try to install it it says that I have to install its package which is `firewall-applet`.

Comment: OK, try that. Ubuntu documentation must be wrong, sorry about that ;(

Comment: @ParanoidPanda _ updated the answer, you might consider filing a bug report against firewalld to either include `firewall-config` as a part of firewalld or update the man page.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly in the `manpage` does it say that it is also installed because I can't find it?

Comment: @ParanoidPanda - at the very top, second line reads "Provided by: firewalld_0.3.4-1_all"

Comment: is the GUI a client gui or a web gui?  I installed it via `yum install firewall-config` but can't figure out how to launch it.  It doesn't add anything into my WHM or cPanel that I can see.  These above posts are 4.5 years old - one would think that time frame there would be a LOT more documentation on the GUI but its like a ghost on the internet as no one ever talks about it, this is probably the ONLY post that provides any detail let alone has an image of what it looks like.  Seems to me firewalld is unsupported and is no longer preferred, but yet comes packaged with Centos 7.

Comment: Heck, even the wiki link above only mentions `firewall-config` 6 times - with no mention on how to install or run it.  Everything about firewalld just seems to be poorly supported and poorly documented.